# androidx settings library and tablet landscape's mode 2-pane layout

Tags: settings, androidx

The new androidx settings library [(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) is a nice new development - but it does not care about the "large tablet in landscape" mode the previous Preference Activity (`AppCompatPreferenceActivity`) did, which displays the headers on the left and the corresponding active fragment on the right half.

Has anybody an idea to implement this?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? Infact, I dont think that Preference Headers are even in AndroidX.

Comment: guess so. No answer, and no solution. One step forward, one backward...